# response.sendRedirect Not Working if html form target is Iframe?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, servlet-filters

I have a form with attribute target=iframe, and I am submitting the form using document.getElementById("form_name").submit();

I have 2 conditions :

1) If control goes to servlet and any form validation gets failed say Captcha then response should be catch in Iframe and error should be displayed on top without refreshing the page.

2) If control goes to Filter before servlet and something breaks inside filter then the page itself should be redirecyed to global error page. The filter logic works fine and redirects succesfully but just for this page it shows the same page however I can see the logs on console of error page that means internally it is hitting error page but on front end it is not getting reflected.

Please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post what have you done in code

Comment: can you post your code for form